# Jquery value of input text/radio is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, undefined

I have multiple links on my page which when you click, there's a div in which a quiz is displayed depending on what link you clicked. The quiz is displayed using ajax. The quiz is made up of multiple divs like this:

```
<div class="displayquiz-particularquestion-container1" > ... </div>
<div class="displayquiz-particularquestion-container2" > ... </div>
...................................................................
<div class="displayquiz-particularquestion-containern" > ... </div>
```

Where `n` is the total number of questions and thus the total number of divs. Each div contains a question in the form of text, and in order to answer the question, each div contains either a text input tag or multiple radio buttons. You write the answer on the ones that have an input tag and check the answer on the ones with a radio button.

Now, I want to be able to loop through all these divs (which is why i gave them unique class names) and check if they contain a text input tag or radio buttons, and get the value of the text input tag or the value of the checked radio button respectively.

So far my code looks like this. NOTE: `check-answers-button` is the id of the button tag that the user presses to check their answers on the quiz. Basically all the questions have been displayed and the user answered them, so now i need to pick out the answers. Also the `displayTo` object represents the main div, in which all the divs which contain the questions are held.

```
$(document).on('click','#check-answers-button',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    // ------ Get the class of the last question container and extract the number from it so as to know how
    //           many questions to loop through

    var numberOfQuestionsClass = displayTo.find('[class*="displayquiz-particularquestion-container"]:last').attr('class');
    var numberOfQuestions = '';

    for(var y = numberOfQuestionsClass.length - 1 ; y > 0; y-- )
        if(!isNaN(numberOfQuestionsClass[y])) numberOfQuestions += numberOfQuestionsClass[y];
        else break;

    // ------ The 'numberOfQuestions' variable now contains the number of questions

    // ------ 'questionsObjectData' will contain all the questions and thier respective answers
    questionsObjectData = {};

    // ------ Loop through all the questions and get the answers
    for(x = 1; x <= numberOfQuestions; x++){
        var question = displayTo.find('.displayquiz-particularquestion-container' + x);


        questionsObjectData['question' + x] = {};

        // ------ Check if the question has a written answer
        if(question.find('input[name=written-answer]').val() === undefined){

            // ------ The question is an option question, get the checked radio button and add it
            //           to the 'questionsObjectData' object

            questionsObjectData['question' + x]['answer'] = question.find('input[name=written-answer]').val();

        }else{

            // ------ The question has a written answer, get the content of the input text field and add it
            //           to the 'questionsObjectData' object

            questionsObjectData['question' + x]['answer'] = question.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();

        }
    }

    console.log(questionsObjectData);

});
```

I use `console.log(questionsObjectData);` in order to see the content of my data so far. The problem is that the `answer` property of each 'question' object inside the main `questionsObjectData` object, are all undefined. Regardless of whether the question had a text tag or a radio button, if the text tag was empty or the radio buttons weren't checked, it's always `undefined` why is that? Do I need to provide the HTML code?

Comment: You actually made it harder by using "unique class names". If they were all the same, you could loop through them using `$(".className").each(function() {`

Comment: I agree, class names can be used for grouping, while ids can be used for uniqueness

Comment: solved it, i needed to replace the code within the `if` with the code within the `else` and vice versa, stupid mistake. I'll look into the `each` function too. Thanks guys

Comment: Why the first `for` loop to figure out the `numberOfQuestions` variable? And why is that variable a string? I would've thought `displayTo.find('[class*="displayquiz-particularquestion-container"]')` would give you all the questions, and the `.length` property of that jQuery object would tell you how many there are. Loop through that object with `.each()` and you can just use `this` for the current item instead of reselecting it by numbered class.